# Sent a date in mysql with vuejs, nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, vue.js

First of all I use for the backend: nodejs and express.js and for the frontend: vuejs and for the database: mysql. I can't send a date that I get from the localStorage to my mysql database. When I send the date, it appears as follows: 0000-00-00. I tried to set my dateLocation field with Date and vachar but it does not work, yet the date is stored in the localStorage in the correct Format.the date I want sent is a date retrieved from a calendar in the format: 12-05-2021. I have also tried converting the date to a string using 'to string' but was unsuccessful. Who can help me ? thanks in advance.

```
//part Frontend vuejs
<script>
methods: {
  sendDate() {
    const dateLoc = {
      dateLocation: localStorage.getItem('dateLocation'),
      dateRetour: localStorage.getItem('dateRetour')
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/location', sendDate)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log({
          error: error
        })
      })
  }
}
</script>

// part Backend nodejs and express js controller location

exports.location = function(req, res) {
    let dateLocation = req.body.dateLocation
    let retourLocation = req.body.retourLocation
    connection.query('INSERT INTO location SET dateLocation = ? , retourLocation = ?, [dateLocation, retourLocation]', (error, results) => {
          if (results) {
            res.status(201).json({
              results
            })
          } else {
            res.status(401).json({
              error: error
            })
          }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be that the query is missing a closure , like while formatting i noticed that the query quotes weren't closed?

Comment: i just did a test with postman, i put the date in english format and it works. Do you know how to convert my date to English format in javascript? thanks @Shujath

Comment: You can format your date in JS, using momentjs or by splitting it up using the Date constructor, check out this [article](https://livecodestream.dev/post/date-manipulation-in-javascript-a-complete-guide/)

Comment: thanks @Shujath i tried something that works it might not be the best way but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, probably it's not the best but it works :).I am sharing the solution I have done for if its can help anyone. Thanks everyone for trying to help me.  :)

```
let newDateDepart = localStorage.getItem('dateDepart')
           console.log(aa)
       
           let year =  newDateDepart.substring(6)
           let month = newDateDepart.substring(3,5,6)
           let day = newDateDepart.substring(2,0)
           let dateDepartFinal= year + "-" + month + "-" + day
           console.log(dateDepartFinal)
          // return 2021-08-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, best I could do without the full code.

```js
data() {
    return { 
        dateLoc: {
            dateLocation : '',
            dateRetour : ''
        } 
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.dataLoc.dateLocation = new Date(localStorage.getItem('dateLocation'));
    this.dataLoc.dateRetour = new Date(localStorage.getItem('dateRetour'));
},
methods: {
    sendDate() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/location', this.dateLoc)
            .then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log({error : error})
            })
    }
}
```

I suggest not to store formatted date in DB, format the it when you need to display. Lookin to this [Date and Time](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bharath , I was able to find out where the problem came from. The problem is with the date format. I sent the format like this: 12-02-2021 and it doesn't work but if I send it with this format: 2021-02-12 it works. Can you please explain to me how to change my date format? thank you